# Mongoose is throwing a cast Exception when converting to Number - Mongoose version 6.6.0

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose to store basic Product information in its database called products. However, when I create an try to perform a bulk insert operation, Mongoose throws an exception that it is not able to cast NAN to Number.  I can verify that the values are all numbers when I print the typeof productId etc. I am posted the code below which shows the schema and the product methods for creating a product from an MS Excel.

```js
        import { Cell, Row } from 'read-excel-file/types';
        import mongoose from 'mongoose';

        const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

        export const productSchema = new Schema(
            {   
                _id: {
                    productId: { type: Number,  required: 'Product Id is required'},
                    productCode: {type: Number, required: [true, 'Product Code is required']},
                },
                productName: { type: String,  required: [true, 'Product Name is required']},
                category: {type:String, required: [true, 'Category is required' ]},       
            }
        );

        export const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

        function createProducts (rows:Row [])  {
            return rows.map(cells => { return createProduct(cells); });
        }

        function createProduct(cells: Cell[]){
            let product = {
                _id:{
                productId: Number.parseInt(cells[0].toString()),
                productCode: Number.parseInt(cells[1].toString())
                },
                productName: cells[2],
                category: cells[3]
            }
            return product
        }
        
        let row:Row[] = getProducts() // Not shown

        const products = createProducts(row)
        
         //Partition in batches of 50 
        const partitionedSet = createPartitions(products, 50)

        for(let product of partitionedSet){  
            let savedResult = await Product.insertMany(product);
        }
```

Here is the error thrown:

```
    {"timestamp":"2023-05-11T21:22:19.722Z","message":"This exception wasn't handled ValidationError: _id.productId: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" (type number) at path \"_id.productId\"\n"}  
    {"timestamp":"2023-05-11T21:22:19.722Z","message":"This exception wasn't handled ValidationError: _id.productCode: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" (type number) at path \"_id.productCode\"\n"}
```

From the errors it is clear what's causing the exception, but I'm baffled the this exception is thrown.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I solve this problem? I am using version 6.6.0 of Mongoose

Comment: typeof NaN is number. You probably have to do an isNaN check

Comment: I did, I printed the whole list of productIds and productCodes and they all showed up as number, i.e. const productCodeType = typeof productCode. I also verified the count of productIds.  Also, the Javascript interpreter would throw a NaN  when Number.parseInt(..) is called if the  value's type did not evaluate to a number.  I can also see all the values in the Excel, they are all numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was including the header row of the sheet which contained the column headers. I removed it and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I was including the header row of the sheet which contained the column headers. I removed it and it all worked fine.

When you included the header row of the sheet, the header row values were treated as data by your code. Since the header row contains non-numeric values (i.e., the column names), attempting to parse them as numbers using `Number.parseInt()` resulted in `NaN` (Not-a-Number) values.

When your `createProduct` function tried to create product objects using these `NaN` values, Mongoose threw a validation error because it was unable to cast `NaN` to the `Number` type specified in your schema.

By removing the header row from the data you're processing, you ensure that only valid, numeric values are passed to the `createProduct` function, which resolves the issue.

In case you need to process Excel files with header rows in the future, you can add a check in your code to skip the header row or use a library like `xlsx` that can read and parse Excel files, and has built-in support for handling headers. Here's an example using the `xlsx` library:

```js
import xlsx from 'xlsx';

function readExcelFile(file) {
    const workbook = xlsx.readFile(file);
    const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

    // This will automatically parse the headers and return an array of objects
    const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);

    return data;
}
```

You can then adjust your `createProduct` function to work with the parsed objects directly:

```js
function createProduct(row) {
    let product = {
        productId: Number.parseInt(row.productId),
        productCode: Number.parseInt(row.productCode),
        productName: row.productName,
        category: row.category,
    };
    return product;
}
```

And finally, adjust your main processing code:

```js
const rows = readExcelFile('path/to/your/excel/file.xlsx');
const products = rows.map(createProduct);

//Partition in batches of 50
const partitionedSet = createPartitions(products, 50);

for (let product of partitionedSet) {
    let savedResult = await Product.insertMany(product);
}
```

By using this approach, you won't need to worry about manually skipping the header row, since the `xlsx` library will handle it for you.

---

Note that you are using the `_id` field in your schema as an object, which is not a recommended practice.
The [`_id` field in a Mongoose schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) should be of type `ObjectId`.

If you want to store `productId` and `productCode` as unique identifiers, you can add them as separate fields in your schema and create a compound index to ensure their uniqueness.

Yes, there are still a few recommendations from my first answer that you might find helpful, even though you have identified and resolved the root cause of the problem.

Update your schema like this:

```js
export const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        productId: { type: Number, required: 'Product Id is required' },
        productCode: { type: Number, required: [true, 'Product Code is required'] },
        productName: { type: String, required: [true, 'Product Name is required'] },
        category: { type: String, required: [true, 'Category is required'] },
    },
    { timestamps: true },
);

productSchema.index({ productId: 1, productCode: 1 }, { unique: true });

export const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

---

Also, while you have resolved the specific issue that led to the `NaN` values, it's still a good idea to include error handling in your code.
This way, if any unexpected issues arise in the future, you can easily identify and address them.

For example, you can update the `createProduct` function to print the row and cell values when an error occurs:

```js
function createProduct(row) {
    let productId = Number.parseInt(row.productId);
    let productCode = Number.parseInt(row.productCode);

    if (isNaN(productId) || isNaN(productCode)) {
        console.log('Error parsing row:', row);
    }

    let product = {
        productId: productId,
        productCode: productCode,
        productName: row.productName,
        category: row.category,
    };
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. I'll add that check to ensure other such errors will be caught, really appreciated!